# FEDEX "Customer not eligable for service"

Tags: error, shipping, fedex

I'm trying to implement FEDEX on my e-commerce system but in the fedex logs I get the error:

```
        [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
        [Notifications] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Severity] => ERROR
                [Source] => crs
                [Code] => 750
                [Message] => Customer not eligible for  service. 
                [LocalizedMessage] => Customer not eligible for  service. 
            )

        [Version] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ServiceId] => crs
                [Major] => 10
                [Intermediate] => 0
                [Minor] => 0
            )
```

This only seems to happen for certain countries so I'm pretty sure the credentials I've passed in are correct.

Under "Ship to allowed countries" it's set to "All allowed countries" and I have a valid shipping from address setup.

I've contacted FEDEX and they said it's to do with something that has been setup on Magento but I have no idea what else it could be. I'm thinking it has something to do with the shipping zones, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the request with the following value:

`[ServiceType] => SMART_POST`

`SMART_POST` is the default Service Type. Please check your area and select available service types such as `PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT` or `STANDARD OVERNIGHT` or `FEDEX EXPRESS SAVER` etc

Hope this will help you.